# Moving Azure VM to another region - Ways to keep the Public IP address?

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

For regulatory reasons, I will soon have to move an Azure VM (classic) from the Netherlands region to the Germany region.

I have read a few blogs about this and believe I understand the process, in particular around copying VHDs from the source region to the new one.

What is more unclear is how to preserve the current VM's public IP address that I have assigned to it.

The IP address is mapped to a DNS host name, which I can easily change, but this VM receives real-time data and it would be best if the same IP address could be preserved to minimize the downtime as much as possible, in particular around the time DNS changes would take to be reflected across the globe.

In summary, my questions are:

1. It is possible to keep / move the public IP address currently used by my VM, after I move said VM to another region.
2. Will the IP address be hosted on the Germany data center, or still in the Netherlands data center? (this may have legal implications with the German data inspecting authorities).
3. Is there any tool or PowerShell script that I can use to make the process easier of migrating VMs to? (I already use ClumsyLeaf CloudExplorer for file management).
4. As part of this migration, process, is it recommendable that I upgrade the VM from the classic model to the "Resource Manager" (ARM) model?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> It is possible to keep / move the public IP address currently used by
>   my VM, after I move said VM to another region.

No. IP address is not movable even within the same region. Additionally, each country has its own block of Ipv4 IPs so you can't use another country IP anyway.

> Will the IP address be hosted on the Germany data center, or still in
>   the Netherlands data center? (this may have legal implications with
>   the German data inspecting authorities).

Germany DC.

> Is there any tool or PowerShell script that I can use to make the
>   process easier of migrating VMs to? (I already use ClumsyLeaf
>   CloudExplorer for file management).

Yes. Try [Migaz](https://github.com/Azure/classic-iaas-resourcemanager-migration/tree/master/migaz)

> As part of this migration, process, is it recommendable that I upgrade
>   the VM from the classic model to the "Resource Manager" (ARM) model?

You can migrate to ARM before migrating to another region or you can do this at one time.